# Android Biometric Authentication how can get the type of authentication (Pin ,pattern,password,fingerprint and face recognition )

Tags: android, biometrics

```
//promptInfo to initialize the pop up title, subtitle and pin password option enabled
        promptInfoWithPin = BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder()
            .setTitle("Login to Android Tutorials Hub")
            .setSubtitle("Biometric Authentication + Pin Password")
.setDescription("Use your fingerprint or pin to access the app")
            .setConfirmationRequired(true)
            .setDeviceCredentialAllowed(true)
            .build()
```

We have used this type of getting the biometric authentication but we are not able to the getauthenticationType() is not working

Comment: What exactly you are dealing with? Is your code not working? or you just want a way to detect activated bio auth on device?

Comment: I need bio and pin, pattern authentication type need once success the authentication we want to authentication type.